# Dynamic font size in GameMaker without loss of resolution

Tags: fonts, game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

GameMaker allows you to select a font size on a font asset, and this scales perfectly without looking pixelated (with anti-aliasing enabled). However, it doesn't seem to be possible to change the font size at runtime or draw text with a specified font size. You are apparently expected to make a seperate font asset for each font size you are going to use. But what if you have to determine font size dynamically at runtime? For example the font size you need could depend on user input or on some runtime calculation, and could change to any value at runtime, not just a limited set.

The `draw_text_transformed` function scales the text by `xscale` and `yscale` values, but it seems to essentially scale the image that is the result of the font being rendered, so if your font has a small font size and you upscale it, it will look very pixelated. This is different to when you change the font size in the font asset, which seems to correctly scale based on vector graphics and supports anti-aliasing. Even if you set the font to a very big font size and then downscale it rather than upscale, it will look worse than a font asset with that font size, since the scaling doesn't seem to use anti-aliasing. Compare:

[image: font comparison]

Top is the downscaled version, bottom is a different font asset with its font size manually set to the desired value.

Is there a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you require text to be drawn at a variety of sizes and scales, distance field fonts ([explanation](https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/2d/fonts/distance-field-fonts)) are the way this is usually handled. There is an [example implementation](https://marketplace.yoyogames.com/assets/8656/distance-field-fonts) for GameMaker.

An alternative is to use `font_add`, which will dynamically generate a texture page for the font from a (vector-based) file.

Comment: I'll look into that distance field font implementation, is there an easy way to make existing font files work with that?

I am aware of font_add, but it doesn't seem right to me to generate a font asset and texture every single time you want to use the same font with a different size, and I probably would have to program my own system to check if a specific font size has been used before then look it up and if not add and save it. I guess I'll have to do that though since GameMaker doesn't seem to provide this simple functionality with their built in font assets.

Comment: So long as your original font is vector-based (TTF/OTF/etc.), you can generate a distance field texture for it with tools such as libGDX's Hiero (linked in the first link).